# Elfinder 2.0 decode filename

Tags: javascript

```
$("#elfinder").elfinder({
    url: 'https://localhost/elfinder',
    handlers: {
        dblclick: function(event, elfinderInstance) {
            var file = event.data.file; //l1_dGVzdC9iYW5uZXJfYmdfaG9yaXpvbnRhbC5qcGc      
        }
    }
});
```

How to decrypt `l1_dGVzdC9iYW5uZXJfYmdfaG9yaXpvbnRhbC5qcGc` into `banner_bg_horizontal.jpg` (real filename) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you do not use Base64

I use it and it works well

[example Base64](http://ntt.cc/2008/01/19/base64-encoder-decoder-with-javascript.html)

Answer (score 1):

For elFinder you'll need to modify the base64 keyStr values + / = to - _ .

```
  var keyStr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP" +
           "QRSTUVWXYZabcdef" +
           "ghijklmnopqrstuv" +
           "wxyz0123456789+/" +
           "=";
```

change to...

```
  var keyStr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP" +
           "QRSTUVWXYZabcdef" +
           "ghijklmnopqrstuv" +
           "wxyz0123456789-_" +
           ".";
```

then strip the prefix "l1_" before decoding